# Rails: additional info with 40x through Ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, unauthorized

In `Rails`, when a user tries to access a page which he doesn't have permission to see, I render a `401` page to him:

```
render :file => "public/401.html", :status => :unauthorized
```

But if it's a `Ajax` request, can I attach more information than "it's a 401 error" to my response? For example, let the client know what permission it need to access this URL.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Ajax you can check with request.xhr?

like:

```
if request.xhr?
  render :json => {:message => "message content", :status => :unauthorized}
else
  render :file => "public/401.html", :status => :unauthorized
end
```